# convert array of numbers into a single number, add 1, then convert back into array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert an array of single digit integers into a single integer, add 1, then convert it back into an array of single digits.

For example: `var arr = ([4,8,6,9])` needs to become `([4,8,7,0])`

But it needs to run in a function, example:

```
function plusArray([4, 8, 6, 9]){

}
```

What's the best way to achieve this using JavaScript?

---

Ok guys, update!

This code is working so far:

```
function arrayUp(arr){
  var toNum = parseInt(arr.join('')) + 1;
  arr = toNum.toString().split('').map(Number);
  return arr;
}
```

Except I am getting an error now. Namely, "Expected: null, instead got: [2]". According to my exercise, "Only positive, single digit integers are allowed in the array so the function should return null if any of the array values are negative or more than 10".

What do I need to adjust in the code above?

Comment: What have you tried so far and why has it failed? Also, please provide more inputs and outputs you'd expect.

Comment: What and why the single integer step? How do you expect to split a single integer back into multiple, by what formula?

Comment: I don't know how, I just know that the array needs to have 1 added to it as if it were an integer. Not sure how to achieve this optimally in JS.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Just increase the last element of an array?

Comment: Yes, the array needs to behave like an integer when 1 is added. Another example: [4, 6, 2, 9] after running the script should return [4, 6, 3, 0]

Comment: A better question is _why_ you need to keep numbers like this.

Comment: Can any of the numbers be negative? What about leading zeros?

Comment: Hold on, the numbers can be negative or be more than 10.

Comment: I edited my question above, can revise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr=[4,8,6,2];
var toNum=parseInt(arr.join(''))+1;
arr=toNum.toString().split('').map(Number);
console.log(arr);//[4, 8, 6, 3]
```

with function:

```
function addOne(arr){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]>9 || arr[i]<-1)return null;
    }
    var toNum=parseInt(arr.join(''))+1;
    arr=toNum.toString().split('').map(Number);
    return arr;
}
var a=[4,8,6,2];
a=addOne(a);
```

Comment: is possible to make a function out of it?

Comment: almost there, a nul should be returned if any of the integers are negative or more than 10. Right now, I am receiving 2 when I run the test.

Comment: it should return null when if more than 9 not 10.

Comment: Sorry Omar, the program will not accept the answer. Please check here for the assignment and the test results I received: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/9nmfvoga/2/

Answer (score -1):

something like:

```
function plusArray(a){
    var mul=1,n=0;
    for (var i=a.length;i;i--){ n += a[i-1]*mul; mul *= 10; }
    n++; a=[];
    while(n){ a.unshift(n % 10); n=Math.floor(n/10); }
    return a;
}
```